# icons cdn for markdown

Tags: github, icons, markdown, profile

I want to update my GitHub profile . I want to add linkedin , VSCode , Nodejs , Reactjs , etc icons to my markdown . I want to know from where I should get these icons link cdn .

I have seen that people are using imgur for it . I don't want to make an account on imgur just for icons ,so is there any other good option to get these icons cdn ?

Comment: Do you think Devicons could help you? https://devicon.dev

Comment: You basically need to find the icons with proper licenses, like public domain ones, and host them yourself. You can store them all in a folder on your profile and link to them.

Comment: @DavidLeal  . Do you have any other way which can benefit me ?

Comment: @M.H.Tajaddini ok..thank you 